# Dynamics 365 Plugin Registration Tool gives permission error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps

When I try to connect to Dynamics 365 CRM with the Plugin Registration Tool I get the following permission error:

> "You don't have permission to access any of the organizations in the
>   Microsoft Common Data Service region that you specified. If you're not
>   sure which region your organization resides in, choose "Don't know"
>   for the CDS region and try again. Otherwise check with your CDS
>   administrator. Parameter name: EMEA"

- I have the System Administrator role
- I can sign-in to the web interface and work with no issues
- I'm sure of our region, tried to login with and without it ("Don't know" option)
- Also tried with an application password as our organization uses multi factor authentication
- Using the latest version of the tool on Nuget (9.0.0.9506 in the about dialog)
- I can connect to my trial server the same way
- We had a user who was able to connect with the same user roles set
- This seems machine and account independent. Other users including the organization creator are getting the same error
- We are directly connected to the internet, no proxies
- One solution I've read suggested cleaning the cache files which don't appear on my system. And we get the same error on clean installations.

Comment: Any two-factor authentication enabled in your company?

Comment: Yes. We also tried with an application password. Normally 2fa dialog appears after signing in for interactive operation, so app password may not be necessary.

Comment: 99% it's 2FA. Application password should do the trick..

Comment: Thanks Sergey. We've tried with an application password with no success. And I remember from our old user that a dialog shows up after you sign in, to let you enter your 2fa password interactively if the organization has enabled multi factor. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by leaving the "Show Advanced" checkbox unchecked and not entering User ID / Password. Then a second dialog opens for credentials and 2FA authentication which just works.

You don't need an application password, as you'll be asked for MFA in the next step.

I don't know how our old teammate was able to sign in with the "Show Advanced" option selected. He was getting the same dialog and continue.

Comment: tried this still doesn;t work. This is extremly annoying

Comment: This worked for me. In my case it worked only when I entered username in small caps.